# How to monitor zero activity in Oracle advanced queue

Tags: oracle11g

We have implemented multiple AQs in our application. Due to few exception scenarios messages don't reach to one of the AQ. So we need to implement monitoring to generate alert if there is no enqueue/deque in a queue from last 10 mins. I tried using SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MAX(ora_rowscn)) function on queue table, but it doesn't return any result if queue is empty at that moment.

Please suggest the best way to implement this..thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a status table - 1 row (per queue you want to monitor).

Anytime the DEQUEUE fires for the queue you want to monitor.
Just do a simply UPDATE of the "LAST_DEQUEUE_TIME" for that record. ;)

Now you just need a process to wake up every ~10 min, and peek at that record.

There might be more "elegant" solutions, however, this would probably be the simplest way to do it.

You can also include a column to tell if DEQUEUE is turned on/off at the moment (ie so if you've disabled DEQUEUE for some maintenance, for example, this status table would know, and the process scanning it would be able to tell - and not "panic") ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick solution Ditto, yes that will work. Though I found an inbuilt solution of using  LAST_ENQUEUE_TIME and LAST_DEQUEUE_TIME fields from GV$PERSISTENT_QUEUES.